# Поиск в папках и подпапках в Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Добрый день.

Необходимо в /sys/bus/usb/devices/ сделать проход по всем подпапкам, в каждой найти файл idVendor считать его значение.

Comment: Какое значение может быть у файла? Или в текстовом файле хранится число?

Comment: А на какую глубину заходить в подкаталоги. Там куча циклических символических ссылок из за которых любая полностью рекурсивная процедура окажется вечной. А на глубину 1 ` find /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/ -name idVendor` отлично их дает и может соотв. для каждого из них команду выполнить

Comment: у find есть ключик `-P` - который говорит "не ходи по ссылкам". Поэтому, `find -P  /sys/bus/usb/devices/` уже решает вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim -P - это его дефолтное поведение. Но он проблему не решает, потому что /sys/bus/usb/devices/ содержит исключительно ссылки и он в них не заходит и соотв. никакие файлы не находит.

Comment: а может проще просто использовать "правильные команды"? Например, так `lsusb | awk '{ print $6; }'`

Comment: Это необходимо для работы с девайсом. Там нет lsusb. Кроме того мне нужен универсальный скрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~
find /sys/devices -iname '*idv*' > ~/idv
cat ~/idv | while read line
do
cat $line
done
rm ~/idv
```

/sys/bus/usb/devices = /sys/devices. 
проверил у себя на Debian 8 без рутовских привилегий

Answer (score 2):

для данного конкретного случая удобно будет воспользоваться программой `tail`:

```
$ tail /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor
==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/idVendor <==
8087

==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/idVendor <==
045e

==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/idVendor <==
046d

==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.3/idVendor <==
058f

==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/idVendor <==
8087

==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/idVendor <==
1d6b

==> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/idVendor <==
1d6b
```